# Firestore transaction - locking at row level or field Level

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

The lock in Firestore is at row level or at field level
From transaction.get , I get the whole row ( unable to find a way to select particular field) , so it appears it's row level
But want to confirm

Answer (score 0):

Optimistic locking for Firestore transactions happen at the document level.  There is no way to lock a field.